# How to pass selected options from a dropdown menu to another page using AJAX

Tags: php, html, arrays, ajax

I have a problem on passing more than one values from a dropdown menu. What I am doing is an attendance system where a dropdown menu containing the choices of attendance status per student. User will then choose the attendance status of each student accordingly, and what I am trying to do is to pass the status that has been chosen to another page.

I am trying to insert the selected attendance status into an array using AJAX and then pass the array to another page. Here's what I have so far:

```
todaysattendance.php
//dropdown menu
<tr>
    <td>  $fetched_fName $fetched_lName  </td> 
    <td> <select name='okselect' id='okselect'>
        <option value='no'> </option>
  <option value='p' name='p' style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>Present</option>
  <option value='ea' name='ea' style='color:#e1c872; font-weight:bold;'>Excused Absent</option>
  <option value='ua' name='ua' style='color:#e34c4c; font-weight:bold;'>Unexcused Absent</option>
  <option value='et' name='et' style='color:blue; font-weight:bold;'>Excused Tardy</option>
  <option value='ut' name='ut' style='color:purple; font-weight:bold;'>Unexcused Tardy</option>
  <option value='sr' name='sr' style='color:black; font-weight:bold;'>School's Representative</option>
  </select></td> </tr>
```

```
todaysattendance.php
//AJAX code
var tempArr = [];
    $("#okselect").change(function()
    {
        var output = getValues(this, function () 
        {
            for (var i=0;i<output.length;i++) 
            {
                tempArr.push(output);
            };
        });
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "add_attendance_check.php", 
        data: {tempArr: tempArr}, 
        success: function(data) {
                   //
                },
                error: function(e) {
                   console.log(e.message);
                }
      });
```

});

```
add_attendance_check.php
   $passed_attstatus = array();
   $thestatus = $_POST['tempArr'];
   array_push($passed_attstatus, $thestatus);
```

But from this coding, let's say I took the attendance status for 10 students, I only managed to get the last student's attendance status. I need help on this. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `$("#okselect").change(function()` will work per change of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

print variable dropdown_value in add_attendance_check you will get the value of selected dropdown.

```
    <form method="post" action="" role="search">
     <select name='okselect' id='okselect'>
    <option value='no'> </option>
  <option value='p' name='p' style='color:green; font-weight:bold;'>Present</option>
  <option value='ea' name='ea' style='color:#e1c872; font-weight:bold;'>Excused Absent</option>
  <option value='ua' name='ua' style='color:#e34c4c; font-weight:bold;'>Unexcused Absent</option>
  <option value='et' name='et' style='color:blue; font-weight:bold;'>Excused Tardy</option>
  <option value='ut' name='ut' style='color:purple; font-weight:bold;'>Unexcused Tardy</option>
  <option value='sr' name='sr' style='color:black; font-weight:bold;'>School's Representative</option>
  </select>
    </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#okselect").change(function() {
        var dropdown_value = $('#okselect').val(); 
                     $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "add_attendance_check.php", 
                    data: {dropdown_value: dropdown_value}, 
                    success: function(data) {
                               //
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                               console.log(e.message);
                        }
                    }); 
    });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a great news, I finally solved the problem. All I need to do is to change this line in todaysattendance.php from

```
<select name='okselect' id='okselect'>
```

into

```
<select name='okselect[]' id='okselect'>
```

In add_attendance_check.php, I simply changed to

```
$passed_attstatus = array();
$thestatus = $_POST['okselect'];
array_push($passed_attstatus, $thestatus);
```

No need for AJAX from the very beginning. Anyway I would like to thank everyone who responded. Have a good day!

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name='okselect' id='okselect' onchange="abc(this.value)">
//your option
</select>

And Ajax call abc function inner abc(value)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!